# "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" on creating a foreign key in MySQL / MariaDB

Tags: mysql

I am having troubles creating a table with foreign keys.

Both table creation is going fine but setting the foreign key fails:

```
ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD CONSTRAINT `table2_fkcolumn_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`fkcolumn`) REFERENCES `table1` (`originalcolumn`)
```

Fails returning: "errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"".

I have read that it could mean that our fields have mismatching columns types. But

```
SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE table_name IN ('table1', 'table2') AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('fkcolumn', 'originalcolumn') ;
```

Gives :

```
int(10) unsigned
int(10) unsigned
```

The DB engine in InnoDB.

I am bit lost.

Just mentionning that the tables are created through Laravel's Eloquent migrations and similar code, gives different results... I can not see what I am missing.

Comment: You might want to include both full table definitions.  That being said, you have a Laravel obfuscation layer at work here, and it could have bugs or quirks.

Comment: I am running the query manually so I am sure it's not laravel. I will try to provide a minimal reproduction code.

Comment: Please show structure of both tables

Comment: Found it ... Leaving this for future lost readers. **I had an error in the naming of the table in the alter statement**. The error message is not very helpful.